# What practical difference does it make between "Word by word" Inspiration and Dynamic Inspiration of the Bible?

Tags: exegesis, bible, inspiration

1. "Word by word" inspiration of the Bible: is the view that each word of the Bible was inspired by God, He miraculously guided the authors to write the exact word He wanted to be written, free from any error.
2. Dynamic Inspiration: Only the idea of the text was inspired, but the selection of the words were left to the human writers, so the thought is inspired, the wording is *dynamic*.

Aside from those definitions, do these views make any practical differences as to *how* someone should approach the Scriptures? How should a Christian study the text.

Comment: None of these ideas are expressed in 2 Timothy 3:16-17, which, as far as I can tell, simply says that God inspired scripture so as to guide its reader into righteousness.

Comment: The first interpretation would theoretically make it harder to justify any discrepancies and contradictions, whereas the second leaves the window open for human error.

Comment: My understanding is that "Word for Word" and "Dynamic Equivalence" are translation strategies and not inspiration descriptors.  I believe both strategies are beneficial and translations produced by each method aid in study;  particularly nowadays where so many interlinear bibles allow one to access the underlying languages.

Comment: I studied these things in school, and the pastor taught me that each word of the Scripture was inspired, these points of view are discussed in the Evangelical Community, and they aren't the only ones:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_inspiration#Evangelical_viewpoint

Answer (score 3):

*All* scripture is given by inspiration.

> All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness:  2 Tomothy 3:16 KJV

. . . . not just the concept in the mind of the author but all of it, every word of it, every letter of it. Else how does one know what was in the mind of the writer ?

Only by the exactitude of the letters he wrote on the page.

As the psalmist heads each section of Psalm 119 with the letters of the Hebrew alphabet, so should the reader of scripture pay attention to every single letter.

Otherwise, the exposition of scripture becomes mere opinion.

So-called 'dynamic equivalence' merely opens the floodgates of false interpretation,  scattered opinions and irrelevant comment.

> Thy **words** were found, and I did eat them; and thy word was unto me the joy and rejoicing of mine heart: [Jeremiah 15:16 KJV]